# how i can passing object from array to another array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

welcome

i have Array in java this Array have 5 Element

each Element have Object : name - id - salary

i need to check salary for each object if salary < 500 move this object to another array and if salary > 500 keep this object in this array dont action

my code give me null pointer Expention .. why ?

this is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class test
{

public static void main(String[] args)

{

    emp[] Myarray = new emp[1]; // salary grater than 500
    emp[] Myarray2 = new emp[1]; // salary less than 500



    for(int i = 0; i<Myarray.length; i++)
    {

        Myarray[0].set_name("Saif");
        Myarray[0].set_id(2014106);
        Myarray[0].set_salary(155);

        Myarray[1].set_name("sara");
        Myarray[1].set_id(2014100);
        Myarray[1].set_salary(155);

        Myarray[2].set_name("ahmad");
        Myarray[2].set_id(2014101);
        Myarray[2].set_salary(155);

        Myarray[3].set_name("rawan");
        Myarray[3].set_id(2014103);
        Myarray[3].set_salary(155);

        Myarray[4].set_name("khalil");
        Myarray[4].set_id(2014104);
        Myarray[4].set_salary(155);

        if (Myarray[i].get_salary() < 500)
        {
         emp x = new emp();
         Myarray2[i].set_name(x.get_name());
         Myarray2[i].set_id(x.get_id());
         Myarray2[i].set_salary(x.get_salary());

       }

}

}

}
```

Comment: 1) `emp[] Myarray = new emp[1];` - only setting up to hold for `one` element  2) you initialised the memory, but you do not add any elements e.g. `myArray[0] = new Emp ();`

Comment: how i can fix this ? please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: this code is not really match your requirement in what you want to do, but I'll just give some fast fix to your code*

**EDIT**

While this answer is right for what OP needed at the moment, but I believe that [Mick Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42918027/7702375) is a better approach for this kind of requirement, as I note above

**END EDIT**

There are many error in your code, please check the comment on the code bellow to see what the change and the reason why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // let Myarray and Myarray2 hold max 5 element
        emp[] Myarray = new emp[5]; // salary grater than 500 
        emp[] Myarray2 = new emp[5]; // salary less than 500

        // initialize Myarray[0] before 'using' it else it will rise Null Pointer Exception
        Myarray[0] = new emp()
        Myarray[0].set_name("Saif");
        Myarray[0].set_id(2014106);
        Myarray[0].set_salary(155);

        // initialize Myarray[1] before 'using' it else it will rise Null Pointer Exception
        Myarray[1] = new emp()
        Myarray[1].set_name("sara");
        Myarray[1].set_id(2014100);
        Myarray[1].set_salary(155);

        // initialize Myarray[2] before 'using' it else it will rise Null Pointer Exception
        Myarray[2] = new emp()
        Myarray[2].set_name("ahmad");
        Myarray[2].set_id(2014101);
        Myarray[2].set_salary(155);

        // initialize Myarray[3] before 'using' it else it will rise Null Pointer Exception
        Myarray[3] = new emp()
        Myarray[3].set_name("rawan");
        Myarray[3].set_id(2014103);
        Myarray[3].set_salary(155);

        // initialize Myarray[4] before 'using' it else it will rise Null Pointer Exception
        Myarray[4] = new emp()
        Myarray[4].set_name("khalil");
        Myarray[4].set_id(2014104);
        Myarray[4].set_salary(155);

        // Move iteration here as you only need it after you set the content of each element
        for(int i = 0; i<Myarray.length; i++)
        {
            if (Myarray[i].get_salary() < 500)
            {
                // Get emp from current array
                emp x = Myarray[i];
                // create new object for Myarray2[i] here before 'using' it else it will rise Null Pointer Exception
                Myarray2[i] = new emp();
                Myarray2[i].set_name(x.get_name());
                Myarray2[i].set_id(x.get_id());
                Myarray2[i].set_salary(x.get_salary());

                // since you say Myarray only hold salary greater than 500, i assume you need to remove it here.
                Myarray[i] = null;
            }
        }

        // EDIT: show the content
        for(int i = 0; i<Myarray.length; i++)
        {
            if (Myarray[i] != null)
            {
                // print here, for example
                System.out.println("name " + Myaarray[i].get_name());
            }
        }

        // the same goes for Myarray2
        for(int i = 0; i<Myarray2.length; i++)
        {
            if (Myarray2[i] != null)
            {
                // print here, for example
                System.out.println("name " + Myaarray2[i].get_name());
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

in the end, you may need to sort both **Myarray** and **Myarray2** so that the **null** element was moved to the end of the array.

Comment: oh thanks sidhi artha but i need some help please i need to print the two array .. i write this sop code but give me null pointer why ? how i can fix ?

Comment: // since you say Myarray only hold salary greater than 500, i assume you need to remove it here.
                Myarray[i] = null;
                
                   
            }
             System.out.print(Myarray[i].get_name());
                  System.out.print(Myarray[i].get_id());
                  System.out.print(Myarray[i].get_salary());
        }
    } 
}

Comment: @saifmaher see the edit, but you may consider Mick answer for the right way to do your particular requirement

Answer (score 1):

I think the Nullpointer exception comes from the array em[] never being assigned a value.  In other words, it needs the keyword 'new' for the array to be able to hold an object.  I tried to write a quick version of your program - just separated into two classes.  The Emp class deals with creating employee's and the Test class adds them into an array that will be sorted.  Hope this helps!  :)

```
public class Emp
{

private String name;
private int id;
private int salary;

//Overloaded constructor - used to create Employee objects
public Emp(String name, int id, int salary)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.salary = salary;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId()
{
    return id;
}


public void setId(int id)
{
    this.id = id;
}


public int getSalary()
{
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(int salary)
{
    this.salary = salary;
}
}
```

Test class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test
{

public static void main(String[] args)

{
    //array to store all emp objects
    Emp[] company =
            { new Emp("Saif", 5014100, 155), new Emp("sara", 2014100, 40), new Emp("ahmad", 2014101, 155),
                    new Emp("fawan", 2014103, 568), new Emp("khalil", 2014104, 3000) };

    //creating arrays to store sorted Emp objects in - both have a size of 5 b/c there are only 5 students
    ArrayList<Emp> whiteCollarEmployee = new ArrayList<>();// salary grater than 500
    ArrayList<Emp> blueCollarEmployee = new ArrayList<>(); //salary less than 500


    //for-each loop to check each element in the array
    for (Emp emp : company)
    {

        //check employees salary
        if (emp.getSalary() < 500)
        {
           blueCollarEmployee.add(emp);
        }

        if(emp.getSalary() > 500)
        {
           whiteCollarEmployee.add(emp);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Employee's making more than 500");
    //display employee's making more than 500
    for(Emp emp : whiteCollarEmployee)
    {
        System.out.println(emp.getName() + " makes $" + emp.getSalary());
    }
    System.out.println("\nEmployee's making less than 500");
    //display employee's making less than 500
    for(Emp emp : blueCollarEmployee)
    {
        System.out.println(emp.getName() + " makes $" + emp.getSalary());
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) if you want a Array to hold four elements, you should do this:`emp[] myArray = new emp[4];`
2) you can add a element to a Array by this:

```
 Emp emp = new Emp();
    emp.set_name('test');
    myArray[0] = emp;
```